# schema_search_path is not the same during an enable_extension and a create_table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations, heroku-postgres

following the heroku postgres changes I've been trying to find an "elegant"-ish solution to dealing with the extensions needing to be installed in a distinct schema (`heroku_ext`) and I've come up with this

```rb
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  def enable_extension(name)
    extension_schema = if schema_exists?('heroku_ext')
                         'heroku_ext'
                       else
                         'public'
                       end

    puts "enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA #{extension_schema}"
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"#{name}\" WITH SCHEMA \"#{extension_schema}\""
  end
end
```

This seems to work fine locally (the extensions get automatically installed in the right schema (if I create a `heroku_ext` schema in advance it works)

But when trying to deploy this to heroku I'm getting an odd behaviour, I've added some extra logs to try and figure this one out so here's the updated code.

TL;DR for those that don't care too much about the changes: I'm logging the schema_search path to see its value and update it if necessary during the `enable_extension` call and I've also added the same logging to the `create_table` method (I just copy-pasted it from the official repo and added the log for that one)

```rb
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  def enable_extension(name)
    extension_schema = if schema_exists?('heroku_ext')
                         'heroku_ext'
                       else
                         'public'
                       end
    current_path = schema_search_path
    puts "Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is \"#{current_path}\""
    if current_path.exclude? extension_schema
      self.schema_search_path = "#{current_path},#{extension_schema}"
      puts "Updated SCHEMA SEARCH PATH to \"#{current_path},#{extension_schema}\""
    end

    puts "enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA #{extension_schema}"
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"#{name}\" WITH SCHEMA \"#{extension_schema}\""
  end

  def create_table(table_name, id: :primary_key, primary_key: nil, force: nil, **options)
    td = create_table_definition(table_name, **extract_table_options!(options))

    if id && !td.as
      pk = primary_key || ActiveRecord::Base.get_primary_key(table_name.to_s.singularize)

      if id.is_a?(Hash)
        options.merge!(id.except(:type))
        id = id.fetch(:type, :primary_key)
      end

      if pk.is_a?(Array)
        td.primary_keys pk
      else
        td.primary_key pk, id, **options
      end
    end

    yield td if block_given?

    if force
      drop_table(table_name, force: force, if_exists: true)
    else
      schema_cache.clear_data_source_cache!(table_name.to_s)
    end

    puts "Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is \"#{schema_search_path}\""
    sql_query = schema_creation.accept td
    puts "EXECUTING CREATE TABLE WITH \"#{sql_query}\""
    result = execute sql_query

    unless supports_indexes_in_create?
      td.indexes.each do |column_name, index_options|
        add_index(table_name, column_name, **index_options, if_not_exists: td.if_not_exists)
      end
    end

    if supports_comments? && !supports_comments_in_create?
      if table_comment = td.comment.presence
        change_table_comment(table_name, table_comment)
      end

      td.columns.each do |column|
        change_column_comment(table_name, column.name, column.comment) if column.comment.present?
      end
    end

    result
  end
end
```

and here's the sort of output I'm getting:

```bash
-- enable_extension("hstore")
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public,heroku_ext"
enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext
   -> 0.0894s
-- enable_extension("pg_stat_statements")
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public,heroku_ext"
enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext
   -> 0.0187s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public,heroku_ext"
enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext
   -> 0.0034s
-- enable_extension("unaccent")
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public,heroku_ext"
enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext
   -> 0.0121s
-- enable_extension("uuid-ossp")
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public,heroku_ext"
enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext
   -> 0.0073s
# ...
-- create_table("public.some_table_name", {:id=>:uuid, :default=>#<Proc:0x0000558787a72e70 /app/db/migrate/primary/timestamped_migration_file.rb:24 (lambda)>, :force=>:cascade})
Current SCHEMA SEARCH PATH is "public"
EXECUTING CREATE TABLE WITH "CREATE TABLE "public"."some_table_name" ("id" uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)"
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 1: ...ublic"."some_table_name" ("id" uuid DEFAULT uuid_gener...
```

As you can see during the `enable_extension` phase of the migration there are 2 things that can be noticed:

1. the `heroku_ext` is correctly detected
2. the `heroku_ext` schema is already in the `schema_search_path` (no logs for the update of its value in the output)

And during the `create_table` phase of the migration there's one odd thing that happens:

1. The `schema_search_path` is different and does not have the `heroku_ext` schema in it.

I've already tried adding it in the `database.yml` file but it doesn't seem to change anything.

For more context too, these two migrations happen in the same migration file (since they are the first migrations that were created) so `enable_extension` happens and then immediately after the `create_table` calls start.

Answer (score 0):

This was a complete PEBCAK ‍♂️ I had this in my migration file in between the `enable_extension` lines and the `create_table` ones

```rb
connection.schema_search_path = 'public'
```

which would explain why the schema changed...